# Which of the Dune on screen adaptations is truer to the book, the movie or the miniseries?

Tags: dune, adaptation-comparison

I want to introduce my kids to *Dune*. They're not old enough to read the original book. Which would be more appropriate for them, the 80s movie or the more recent miniseries? Which follows the book more accurately?

Comment: There's a bunch of questions here. If you picked one, it would probably be a lot more answerable and less "opinion-based".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The miniseries is more literal, but I think the film captures the essence of the book better. IIRC there is a nude scene in the miniseries. How old are the kids? The miniseries is long and a bit slow, the film may hold their attention better.

Comment: This seems like it would have been better off as a comment.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  The Lynch film is interesting in its own right, but the ending of the movie runs completely contrary to the purpose of the novels.  The mini-series (and its sequel) have their own flaws, I don't deny that, but they are at least truer to the original story *and the original intent of Frank Herbert's story*